# 15 instances of Magento or 1 / 2 instances of Magento

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

I plan to have 15 different websites will sell the same products but will be in different languages connected to the domains. For example www.shop-a.it will be Italian, www.shop-b.de will be in German and www.shop-c.co.uk will be in English and so on. Is it best to have 15 different Magento websites with 1 store in each or is it best to have 1 or 2 websites with up to 7 stores in each.

Comment: 1. It would be better if the users can select their language
2. And customers from Italy should be redirected to .it, customers from Germany to .de and so on

Answer (score 2):

There is no correct answer for your question based on the information you provided.
Both approaches are equally valid.
But this will help you decide.

I would go with the 1 website 15 store views approach but if the answer to at least one of the questions below is "YES" or "Maybe" then you need to have 15 websites with one store view each.

- Do you want the users for `www.shop-a.it` to NOT have access automatically to `www.shop-b.de`?
- Do you have at least one product that will have a different price on at least 2 websites?
- Do you plan to have promotions that will apply to `www.shop-a.it` and will not apply to `www.shop-b.de` ?
- Do you plan to have different category trees for at least 2 websites? (I'm not talking about just translating the categories - but a different tree structure all together)
- Do you plan to have different payment methods on at least 2 websiste?

Comment: In answer to your questions 
Yes we plan to have a product to be a different price. So in UK it could be £5.99 and in German it might be €10

Yes we plan to have different promotions across the different sites. 

We maybe have different payment methods for the different sites. 

Are the above not possible if we have 15 stores views in 1 instance?

Comment: @user3305256 I wasn't expecting an answer to the questions. I said if the answer is "yes/maybe" to at least one of the question then you have to make 15 websites.  What you need is not possible with the 1 website/15 store views approach because the scope of the 'price' attribute is `website` and you can only set promotions at the website level, not the store view level. So I guess now the answer to your question is simple.  15 website - 1 store view each.

Comment: @user3305256. And just to make sure I was clear enough (maybe I wasn't)... you can use only 1 magento instance and create 15 websites from `System->Manage stores`.

Answer (score 0):

You can have one magento installation in base domain. You can create multiple stores , like each store for one language. You can ping each store to the separate domain .

Answer (score 0):

As you have mentioned that you would be selling same products on all websites, then it will be better to have 1 installation of Magento and manage multiple website environment from single admin panel.

Reasons why to choose 1 magento with multi websites setup:

- 1 time product entry for all websites.
- single admin area to manage all customers and orders.

It will be better (in my opinion), because by using single Magento it will be easy to manage for you.